# Simple for loop for iterating 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists

```
Numberset1 = [10,11,12]
Numberset2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and i want to display output by manipulating the lists, the expected output is

```
10 1
10 2
10 3
10 4
10 5
11 2
11 3
11 4
11 5
11 1
12 3
12 4
12 5
12 1
12 2
```

Since the 2nd number in first list should start from the second number from the second list i tried enumerating it and created another list

```
test=[j for i, o in enumerate(Numberset2) for j in Numberset2[i:] + Numberset2[:i] ]
```

The code i have tried is as follows

```
Numberset1 = [10,11,12]
Numberset2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
test=[j for i, o in enumerate(Numberset2) for j in Numberset2[i:] + Numberset2[:i] ]
for D in Numberset1:
    for j in test:
        print(D,j)
```

The output i am getting is

```
10 1
10 2
10 3
10 4
10 5
10 2
10 3
10 4
10 5
10 1
10 3
10 4
10 5
10 1
10 2
10 4
10 5
10 1
10 2
10 3
10 5
10 1
10 2
10 3
10 4
11 1
11 2
11 3
11 4
11 5
11 2
11 3
11 4
11 5
11 1
11 3
11 4
11 5
11 1
11 2
11 4
11 5
11 1
11 2
11 3
11 5
11 1
11 2
11 3
11 4
12 1
12 2
12 3
12 4
12 5
12 2
12 3
12 4
12 5
12 1
12 3
12 4
12 5
12 1
12 2
12 4
12 5
12 1
12 2
12 3
12 5
12 1
12 2
12 3
12 4
```

I know that i am iterating the test and that is why i am getting these many numbers, how can i make sure that i am getting only the expected output

Comment: Use `zip()` here

Comment: @tanaydin I don't think this is a duplicate of that question, the requirements here are a bit more specific if you check the example output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just print in a double loop using shifted indices and modulo:

```
Numberset1 = [10,11,12]
Numberset2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i,n in enumerate(Numberset1):
    for j in range(len(Numberset2)):
        print(n,Numberset2[(j+i) % len(Numberset2)])
```

result:

```
10 1
10 2
10 3
10 4
10 5
11 2
11 3
11 4
11 5
11 1
12 3
12 4
12 5
12 1
12 2
```

or generate the tuples using list comprehension:

```
[(n,Numberset2[(j+i) % len(Numberset2)]) for i,n in enumerate(Numberset1) for j in range(len(Numberset2))]
```

which gives:

```
[(10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 3), (10, 4), (10, 5), (11, 2), (11, 3),
 (11, 4), (11, 5), (11, 1), (12, 3), (12, 4), (12, 5), (12, 1), (12, 2)]
```

*how it works*:

`Numberset2[(j+i) % len(Numberset2)]` is accessing the jth index of `Numberset`, with, added the offset of the outer bound (0, 1, ... etc...)

If we leave `j+i` it reaches `len(Numberset2)` and we get array out of bounds exception. To make sure that index is shifted *and* remains in range, we add a modulo operator so it wraps around.

Comment: But it will fail if Numberset1 doesn't start with 10, for example if Numberset1 = [11,12,13], or I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @obchardon You can just test it with Jean's code, it doesn't fail.

Comment: @Arne Yes, the code work, I wanted to said that it can't be generalized. So for example if the first Number of Numberset1 = 11, then the offset will still be 0.

Comment: This one works, never knew that there is such a thing called shifted indices

Comment: can you pls give me some link to study more about this?

Comment: Here's another one-liner that unfortunately needs an import from `itertools`: `[(i, j) for it in [cycle(Numberset2)] for i in Numberset1 for (j, _) in zip(it, Numberset2)]`

Comment: yes cycle is also cool. why "unfortunately"? well it's harder to understand for beginners but avoids the infamous `range(len())` that I had to use.

Comment: @Python_newbie I've edited my post to explain the modulo "trick"

Comment: The unfortunately was because with the import it's not really a one-liner.  But the real issue is that it uses `zip()` to gobble one extra item from the iterator.  I think experienced Python programmers would skip over it without thinking about it, so it's more golf than anything.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks for explaining it

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
Numberset1 = [10,11,12]
Numberset2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

You can make an infinite looping iterator over `Numberset2` using `itertools.cycle` take a slice of the iterator using `itertools.islice` and skip one after each loop using `next()`:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

it = cycle(Numberset2)
for i in Numberset1:
    for j in islice(it, len(Numberset2)):
        print(i, j)
    skipped1 = next(it)
```

Comment: This one works as well :-o

Comment: how do we come to know about all these different things, thanks for the answer